# What plant is this? A succulent of some sort

Tags: identification, succulents

It can get very dense and plump but I can't seem to figure out what combo of light and water it needs to keep it that way. It gets baked by too much direct light and it has tendency to get really leggy if its in the shade. If I knew the name I could get some insight into its natural environment.

[image: Plant]

[image: Plant 2]

Comment: I don't recognise it in its current state, but are there drainage holes in that container to let out excess water? What type of potting medium have you used? And have you ever seen any flowers, and when it gets 'plump' how tall does it get?

Comment: first of all a succulent needs very little water,they store water, but proper drainage is a must for any plant. i would re-pot in a proper container,give adequate light, let it go and see what you get.

Comment: Do they have bulbs? Looking the dried leaves, I would go toward *liliaceae* family and not succulent plants.

Comment: Carpobrotus acinaciformis?

Comment: I'm curious about the root structure too. Would you mind pulling one up and giving us a description and a picture? I assume one of the brown ones would be fine, so you don't have to damage a thriving plant! I see what might be a good candidate in the top left part of your second picture.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it looks like an Aloe of some sort. The whitish spotting on the leaves is a good indicator. Does resemble some ice plants though, if it blooms with outer-space looking daisys an inch wide its that. One thing about ANY succulent type plant though is that the root structures are going to want to breathe. Most succulents respirate through their roots and so even if you have just given one its thourough soaking (after having the soil dry out completely) the growing medium is going to want enough gravel, grit, sand, bark-whatever so that the roots will continue to get air at all times. Full sun for sure as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a type of Aloe to me, but I can't be sure.